# scanf_s not returning any value

Tags: c, scanf

I am running the program below, and the only output I get is the question "whats your number?". 
If I then enter any number, e.g. 3, then nothing further happens.
Can anyone help?
I am using VS2017.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    printf("whats your number?\n");
    scanf_s(" %d", &x);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    getchar();  
}
```

Comment: Did you press the *`Enter`* key after your input?

Comment: Thanks for asking! Yes I did, unfortunately no result.

Comment: I have just tried your example as-is in vs2017.  It works just fine for me, except that `getchar()` will not wait, use `_kbhit()` from conio.h  instead.

Comment: [Can't replicate](http://rextester.com/ODZS55770).

Comment: `scanf_s` not returning any value? You have ignored the return value of `scanf_s`. Try `int retval = scanf_s(" %d", &x);` and now `retval` will hold the return value from `scanf_s`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying both of you, although that really worries me since I may have some VS2017 issue then.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy no use to use `_kbhit` since the `newline` still is in the input buffer.

Comment: It *could* be a problem with your program not waiting at the `getchar` as you expect it. That's because the `Enter` key is in the input buffer, but it's not consumed by the `scanf_s` call and so the `getchar` call reads it and the program exits.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I suspect you are referring to the length parameter required by `%c` and `%s` and `%[]` format specifiers in this horrible not-at-all-safer function.

Comment: @weathervane:  Since I had downloaded the example, I did try `while (!_kbhit()) ;`  before posting, it works just fine.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy interesting, yes `_kbhit` does ignore anything already in the input buffer, perhaps because it's a different buffer. If I use `_kbhit` followed by `_getch` the original `newline` is still waiting to be read by `getchar` afterwards.

Comment: @WeatherVane.  I cannot say that I wasn't surprised that `getchar()` did not wait either.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi `scanf_s` doesn't require an parameter for `%d` items, only `%s` items: [`scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l)

Comment: Note that `scanf_s()` is an optional standard function defined in Annex K of the C11 standard. It is recommended by Microsoft; it isn't implemented on other systems AFAIK.  But it is a 'standard' function at the moment, though there is a suggestion that it will be dropped or deprecated in the next version of the C standard.

Comment: @chronokitsune  `scanf_s("", &x)` does nothing and returns immediately.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy OK? I'm uncertain what relevance your comment has to this question. My comment was explaining that an extra parameter denoting the length of a buffer is only required for character and string formats, not integers, floats, etc.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy you'll have to read the [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) to see what chronokitsune meant. Difference between *format specifier* and *additional  parameter*.

Comment: Sorry @ChronoKitsune, It seem I've misread your statement.

Comment: hi all, thank you for all the good comments and suggestions. I tried most of them and I ended up getting this to work by adding a getchar() extra in the code right after scanf_s. The rest of the code is identical.